# multiprocessing (HoG features) in Python - Empty arrays returned

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing

Trying to extract HoG features on a large data set of images - 70K in total.
So test_X is 28x28x70000
I am trying to use Pool. Trying out the first 10 images

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_hog(inputImg):
    fd,hi=hog(inputImg, orientations=4, pixels_per_cell=(4, 4),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True, multichannel=False)
    return fd

with Pool(5) as p:
    V = p.map(get_hog,test_X[:,:,range(0,10)]))
```

What I endup with empty arrays in V.

Probably the pass of data to the function is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in multi-processing in python, 
one should always try and give the callbacks methods to store the return data from the process.
so for your example we can use the Pool and run the pool over the list of images in your case it is `test_X` and let the call back handle the data returned by each process in the pool.
here is the example code:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
V=[]
test_X = np.transpose(test_x)
def get_hog(inputImg):
    fd,hi=hog(inputImg, orientations=4, pixels_per_cell=(4, 4),
                cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True, multichannel=False)
    return fd

def poolCallback(returnDataFromPool):
    global V
    V.append(returnDataFromPool)

p = Pool(5)
for x in test_X:
    p.apply_async(get_hog ,args=(x,),callback=poolCallback)    
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: The code line p.apply_async(get_hog,x),callback=poolCallback)     gives me invalid syntax error

Comment: Note that I have added the image dimensions to the question.

Comment: Nope am still getting an empty V, probably we change the for loop?

Comment: sorry there was an error i have edited the code this should work

Comment: Hmmm...works, but the results seem incorrect. I think the loop needs to iterate over the images. I am getting 28x70000 as a result. Proabably need to pass on the images as 28x28

Comment: yea , you can update the get_hog function to do this preprocessing too ?

Comment: I did not understand what you meant

Comment: the code above assumes that the test_x is the collection of images and x is the current image that you want to process.
And you can add any preprocessing step you want in you get_hog function.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Actually the images are 28x28 grayscale images [28x28] so the storage is in numpy array i.e. [28x28x70000
]

Comment: happy to help .. I actually once worked with hog feature but i used the ones in opencv i guess. and in that i was able to alter the feature length by updating the nbins property of the histograms.

Comment: Still not solved. The problem persists of getting 28x7000. Check the numpy array as well

Comment: can you share what the shape of image in the get_hog function?

Comment: The image passed onto hog is 28x28, a numpy array.

Comment: I can confirm that the function if changed to return the image itself instead of hog, returns a list. I redid the code. Pasting the code lines here. "test_X_28x28 = np.squeeze(test_X.reshape(28,28,-1))
import multiprocessing 
def f(inputImg):
    return inputImg

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
r = pool.map(f,test_X_28x28[:,:,range(0,10)])"

Comment: When I run the code above, i get a list of 28 items. Each internal item being 28x10. I dont understand why this happens

Comment: lets say you add all the files in folder. traverse that folder using os.listdir and then save the absolute path in the test_x then run the above code. but in get_hog function you read the image from the path and then do the processing ? cause i think the error is somewhere in the way you build test_x

Comment: Thats not a good approach i think. I need this to work as I cant keep making copies of data for every datase I use. I now confirmed that the mapping somehow messes up the 28x28 array. Probably its expecting a list of images 28x28, while I have an ND array of 28x28x70000. So how do I convert the nd array into a 28x28 list of 70000 images?\

Comment: the map doesnot messes up with the code . its just spawns new **process** to execute the desired function parallely , I think the error is due to the way how the test_X list is made

Comment: I have rechecked the code. The arrays are same as I have described.

Comment: oh i get it just before the loop transpose the array to 70000x28x28 and then it should work.because right now the code is looking at the array as 28 images of dimensions 28x70000 each.

Comment: Ah you nailed. Its done now. Transpose did the trick! Plz edit your answer to include transpose. I will accept the answer